# Swift Array of Ints - Find Index where the Difference to the Previous Element is Greater than 10

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, int

I have the following array:

```
let array = [1,3,2,1,4,3,99,3,5,2,1,45]
```

I'd like to create a new array - where an element, whose difference to the previous element is greater than 10, is set to 0.

```
// [1,3,2,1,4,3,0,3,5,2,1,0]
```

Currently, I'm creating a new array with the difference, then filtering that array to find those greater than 10, and then comparing those arrays - which I feel overcomplicates everything.

```
let diffArray = zip(array.dropFirst(), array).map(-) 
let filteredArray = diffArray.filter {abs($0) > 10}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot set index of the element. You have to swap two elements or insert it at 0 index, but others will be shifted to the right. Please explain what do you want to do.

Comment: OK, will edit question.

Comment: So the first number just gets a free pass?

Comment: Great question. For the moment yes.

Comment: What will happen to this array? [5, 14, 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first element stays how it is and next elements are mapped. If difference with element from initial array with index -1 is greater then 10, element is "replaced" by 0

```
let array = [1,3,2,1,4,3,99,3,5,2,1,45]

var temp = array
let mapped = [temp[0]] + temp.dropFirst().enumerated().map {
    let condition = abs(temp[$0.offset] - $0.element) > 10
    if condition { temp[$0.offset + 1] = 0 }
    return condition ? 0 : $0.element
}

print(mapped) // [1,3,2,1,4,3,0,3,5,2,1,0]
```

... if you don't want to count with replaced elements, just remove setting elements of `temp` array

```
let array = [1,3,2,1,4,3,99,3,5,2,1,45]

let mapped = [array[0]] + array.dropFirst().enumerated().map {
    let condition = abs(array[$0.offset] - $0.element) > 10
    return condition ? 0 : $0.element
}

print(mapped) // [1,3,2,1,4,3,0,0,5,2,1,0]
```

---

Alternatively, for example if you want to just change your current array, you can add this method to extension of `Array` of `Int`

```
var array = [1,3,2,1,4,3,99,3,5,2,1,45]

extension Array where Element == Int {

    mutating func replace(difference: Int) {
        guard count > 0 else { return }
        self = [self[0]] + self.dropFirst().enumerated().map {
            let condition = abs(self[$0.offset] - $0.element) > difference
            if condition { self[$0.offset + 1] = 0 }
            return condition ? 0 : $0.element
        }
    }

}

array.replace(difference: 10)
print(array) // [1,3,2,1,4,3,0,3,5,2,1,0]
```

Comment: I'll use this answer as it offers two options. Rakesha's answer below works as well.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it. Nothing fancy though.

```
let array = [1,3,2,1,4,3,99,3,5,2,1,45]

func resetValues(withDifference difference: Int, in array: inout [Int]) {
    for index in array.indices.dropFirst() {
        if abs(array[index - 1] - array[index]) >= 10 {
            array[index] = 0
        }
    }
}

resetValues(withDifference: 10, in: &array)
print(array)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of checking `if index == 0` if you start with `var index = 1` ? Simpler would be `for index in array.indices.dropFirst()`. Also note that your `resetValues(difference: 10, array: array)` does not compile (wrong argument labels, missing `&`).

Comment: @MartinR that was some old code i forgot to remove when i changed the logic :x Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can *map* the array while keeping track of the previous element:

```
let a = [1,3,2,1,4,3,99,3,5,2,1,45]

var previous = a.first ?? 0
let b = a.map { elem -> Int in
    defer { previous = elem }
    return elem - previous > 10 ? 0 : elem
}

print(b)
// [1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 0, 3, 5, 2, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is simple enough: loop through all numbers starting from the second one, and replaces ones that are larger by an amount of 10 than the precedent. Now, with Swift's array capabilities, this can be done in one with one function call:

```swift
let array = [1,3,2,1,4,3,99,3,5,2,1,45]

let filteredNumbers = array.indices.map { i in i > 0 && array[i] - array[i-1] > 10 ? 0 : array[i] }
```

A somewhat little complex solution, but which avoids accessing the array by index, and thus can be applied to any sequence/collection:

```swift
let filteredNumbers = array.reduce(into: (0, [Int]())) { $0.1.append($1-$0.0 > 10 ? 0 : $1); $0.0 = $1 }.1
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a discrepancy between your requirement statement and your example.

"an element, whose difference to the previous element is greater than 10, is set to 0" should result in:

```
[1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 0, 0, 5, 2, 1, 0]
```

but your example result is [1,3,2,1,4,3,0,3,5,2,1,0] which suggests that the difference is actually with the "transformed" value of the previous element.

So, for the stated requirement, you could do it like this:

```
let filteredArray = array.enumerated().map{ $0 > 0 && abs($1 - array[$0-1]) > 10 ? 0 : $1 }
```

or like this:

```
let filteredArray = zip([array[0]]+array,array).map{ abs($0-$1) > 10 ? 0 : $1 }
```

which both produce:

```
[1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 0, 0, 5, 2, 1, 0]
```

But, in order to match your example result (difference with the previous transformed value), you should do this:

```
let filteredArray = array.dropFirst().reduce([array[0]]){$0 + [abs($1-$0.last!)>10 ? 0 : $1]}
```

which produces:

```
[1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 0, 3, 5, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, and making it aware to me. You're totally right.